# ASP.NET Core WebApi RavenDB Error during initilize DocumentStore

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ravendb

I have a project WebApi ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) with RavenDB
Versions:

- RavendDB v3.5.3
- ASP.NET Core v1.1
- .NET Framework v4.6.2
- RavenDB.Client v3.5.3

My code:

Startup class

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        DocumentStoreHolder.DatabaseName = "database";
        DocumentStoreHolder.Url = "http://localhost:8080/";
        services.AddSingleton(DocumentStoreHolder.Store);
        services.AddScoped<ISearchRepository, SearchRepository>();
    }
```

DocumentStoreHolder

```
 public class DocumentStoreHolder
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<IDocumentStore> store = new Lazy<IDocumentStore>(CreateStore);
        public static string Url { get; set; }
        public static string DatabaseName { get; set; }

        public static IDocumentStore Store
        {
            get { return store.Value; }
        }

        private static IDocumentStore CreateStore()
        {
            var store = new DocumentStore
            {
                Url = Url,
                DefaultDatabase = DatabaseName
            }.Initialize();

            return store;
        }
    }
```

Repository

```
  public class SearchRepository : ISearchRepository
    {
        private readonly IDocumentStore _store;

        public async Task<string> Add(SearchRavenDto dto)
        {
            using (var session = _store.OpenSession())
            {
                session.Store(dto);
                session.SaveChanges();
                return dto.Id;
            }
        }
    }
```

During initialize of DocumentStore in DocumentStoreHolder class I receive error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'NLog' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.'

After installation NLog v4.4.11 I receive error:

> Raven.Abstractions.Connection.ErrorResponseException: 'replication
>   bundle not activated in database named: '

In another application (Console App .NET Framework) the same code working fine.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Those are exceptions that are handled internally and have no impact on the system.
Just hit F5 in VS and let it run.